# WCF unhandled exception occured during the excution of the current web request

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I have a WCF service that is build in VS2008 
When I publish the service and run it in IIS (32 bit applications are enabled in application pool) then fine, it works.
But when I try debugging the application (platform targets of all the projects are Any CPU), I get the following error:

```
Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web     request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.InvalidProgramException: Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program.

Source Error: 
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request.   Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 
[InvalidProgramException: Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program.]
   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager..ctor() +0
   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.EnsureInitialized() +463
   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.OnEnsureInitialized(Object state) +185
   System.ServiceModel.PartialTrustHelpers.PartialTrustInvoke(ContextCallback callback,     Object state) +314
   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.SafeEnsureInitialized() +209
   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule.ProcessRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)     +295
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +344
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +557
```

What does that error mean??
any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The platform your have for development is *32 bit* and the platform on which you deploy is `64 bit`. Selecting the debug type *AnyCPU* assembly will JIT to *64 bit* code when loaded into `64 bit` process and `32 bit` when loaded into a `32 bit` process. The published assembly / dependent assembly is most probably not compatible for 64 bit and need to be in 32 bit process.

You can read more about choosing the target platform and its impact over [here](http://visualstudiohacks.com/articles/visual-studio-net-platform-target-explained/).

Comment: thanks for your answer, I tried changing to x86 but that generated another error.
I tried running the application on another machine that has VS2008 professional edition (on this machine it is developers edition) and it worked on that machine, so I'm trying to uninstall VS and installing the professional edition now and I'll let you know what happens

Comment: Build it choosing x86 and then deploy the x86 generated assembly

Comment: Adil, that didn't help.
it is not working, I uninstalled VS2008 and installed the professional edition, that didn't help.
I built choosing x86 and that didn't help either, still getting the same error message

Comment: It was working before as you said in the OP, if thats true then you have to do it that way OP ["I have a WCF service that is build in VS2008 When I publish the service and run it in IIS (32 bit applications are enabled in application pool) then fine, it works."]

Comment: it still is working if I run it from IIS, but not when I try to open the project solution and debug the application.
I need to do some changes in the application and I need to trace, I can't trace if it doesn't work in VS